# How do I express an equality as a function of one of the equality's variable?

Tags: functions

Say I have this equality:

```
(-52271 - 200 x + 100 x^2 - 1058 y + 529 y^2)/52900 == 0
```

and I want the same equality, but expressed in a function of x, as in y(x). How do I make Mathematica give me the corresponding function?

Comment: You can use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html?q=Solve) to get this done.

Answer (score 1):

```
eq = (-52271 - 200 x + 100 x^2 - 1058 y + 529 y^2)/52900 == 0;
yy[x_] := y /. Solve[eq, y]
Plot[yy[x], {x, -25, 25}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In this case, the same can be done for example with

```
yy[x_] := y /. {ToRules@Reduce[eq, y]}
```

You may get the ellipse span for example with:

```
Resolve[Exists[#, eq], Reals] & /@ {x, y}
(* {-9 <= y <= 11, -22 <= x <= 24} *)
```

Also, you may plot the domain without solving it:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@eq, 
            Evaluate[Sequence@@(List@@@(Resolve[Exists[#, eq], Reals] & /@ 
                                               {y, x}))[[All, {3, 1, -1}]]], 
           AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Mathematica is full of possibilities!